# Install CentOS 5.4 from Live CD, possible?

Tags: linux

Installing CentOS 5.4 from LiveCD.

They have a Live CD which I downloaded. However, I can't seen to install from the Live CD.

In Ubuntu you can easily install from the LiveCD. Is this not the case with CentOS?

Many thanks for any advice,

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install from the livecd in a "way". The live cd only supports Net Install. You are better off downloading Disk 1 of the 6 and installing from that.